# How to delete a row from JTable while retaining it in the database

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtable

I am trying to delete a row from my `JTable` without sending updates to the bound MySQL database. To clarify: the deleted row should still be stored on the database but deleted from the `JTable` visible in my GUI.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

import com.mysql.*; 

import java.util.*;
public class Days {
private DefaultTableModel tblModel;
JTable days;
private JTextField ttask;
private JTextField ttime;
private JTextField txtSearch;
private Statement st;
private JButton add=new JButton("Add");
private JButton delete= new JButton("Delete");
private JPanel panelinfo;
private PreparedStatement ps;
JFrame frame;
Connection con;
ResultSet r;
public Days(final String s){
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 598, 470);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.setTitle("NoTimeNoLife");
    panelinfo = new JPanel();
    panelinfo.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "Add your Schedule:", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panelinfo.setBounds(243, 76, 329, 135);

    JLabel a1 = new JLabel("Time :");
    a1.setBounds(10, 30, 46, 14);
    panelinfo.add(a1);
    JLabel a2 = new JLabel("Task :");
    a2.setBounds(10, 85, 46, 14);
    panelinfo.add(a2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelinfo);
    panelinfo.setLayout(null);


    add.setBounds(250, 222, 73, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(add);

    delete.setBounds(333, 222, 73, 30);
    frame.getContentPane().add(delete);

    ttime = new JTextField();
    ttime.setColumns(10);
    ttime.setBounds(93, 28, 206, 20);
    panelinfo.add(ttime);

    ttask = new JTextField();
    ttask.setColumns(10);
    ttask.setBounds(93, 84, 206, 20);
    panelinfo.add(ttask);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(null, "DisplayId", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
    panel.setBounds(10, 76, 230, 86);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setLayout(null);

    txtSearch = new JTextField();
    txtSearch.setBounds(10, 26, 210, 20);
    panel.add(txtSearch);
    txtSearch.setColumns(10);

    String [] columnNames = {"id", "Time", "Task"};
    days = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(null, new Object[]{"id", "Time","Task"}));
    tblModel = (DefaultTableModel) days.getModel();
    days = new JTable(tblModel){
          public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int colIndex) {
          return false; //Disallow the editing of any cell
          }
          };
            days.setBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(0, 0, 0)));
            days.setBounds(55, 314, 496, 116);
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(days);
            scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(452, 150));
            JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
            p1.setBounds(49, 263, 523, 159);
            p1.add(scrollPane);
            frame.getContentPane().add(p1);
```

BTW - can anybody explain to me the meaning of the following snippet: `(Component[] com)`? I copied this code so that table wouldn't be editable unless permission is given however I don't understand how it works as a whole.

```
    Component[] com = panelinfo.getComponents();  
            //Inside you action event where you want to disable everything  
            //Do the following  
            for (int a = 0; a < com.length; a++) {  
                 com[a].setEnabled(false);  
            }  

            frame.getContentPane().add(p1);
            try {
                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing1","root", "password");


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            displaydays(s); 
           add.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {



                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

                    if(add.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Add")){              //equalsIgnoreCase ignores case sensitive

                    add.setText("Save");
                    delete.setText("Cancel");
                    days.setEnabled(false);
                    Component[] com = panelinfo.getComponents();  
                    //Inside you action event where you want to disable everything  
                    //Do the following  
                    for (int a = 0; a < com.length; a++) {  
                         com[a].setEnabled(true);  
                    }  
                    clear();
                    ttime.requestFocus();
                    }else{

                    int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to save this record?", "Message",  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                    if(a==0){

                        //try{
                            try {
                                st=con.createStatement();
                                if (arg0.getSource() == add){
                                    ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO "+s+" (Time, Task) values('" + ttime.getText() + "','" + ttask.getText() + "')");
                                }else{
                                ps=con.prepareStatement("UPDATE "+s+" set Time='" + ttime.getText() + "',Task ='" + ttask.getText() + "'where id ='" + ttime.getText() + "'" ); 

                                }
                                ps.executeUpdate();

                        defautview();
                        displaydays(s);


                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }


                    }


                }
                });
```

This is my "Delete" button which is supposed to delete data from the `JTable` but not from the database (currently my "Delete" button is deleting from the `JTable` AND the database).

```
 delete.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                        int a = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to delete this record?", "Message",  JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

                        if(a==0){

                        try {
                            st = con.createStatement();

                            ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from "+s+" where id ='" + txtSearch.getText() + "'");
                            System.out.println(ps);
                            ps.executeUpdate();
                            displaydays(s);
                            clear();

                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        }

                    }
                });

         days.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    int selectedRowIndex = days.getSelectedRow();
                    //int selectedColumnIndex = tblList.getSelectedColumn();
                    String selectedObject = (String) days.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0);

                txtSearch.setText(selectedObject);
                search(s);

                }
             });
}











    void defautview() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        add.setText("Add");
        delete.setText("Delete");
        days.setEnabled(true);
        Component[] com = panelinfo.getComponents();  
        //Inside you action event where you want to disable everything  
        //Do the following  
        for (int a = 0; a < com.length; a++) {  
             com[a].setEnabled(false);  
        }  
        clear();
    }
    void clear() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ttime.setText("");
        ttask.setText("");// set time and task clear.
    }

     void displaydays(String s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                 st = con.createStatement();

                r = st.executeQuery("select * from "+s);
                tblModel.getDataVector().removeAllElements();
                while(r.next()){

                    tblModel.addRow(new Object[]{r.getString("id"),r.getString("Time"),r.getString("Task")});// Display the Table into tblModel using ResultSet

                }

            } catch (SQLException e2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("error");
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
    void search(String s){
        try {
            st = con.createStatement();

         ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+s+" WHERE id='"+ txtSearch.getText() + "'");
         if(rs.next()){
             ttime.setText(rs.getString("Time").toString());
             ttask.setText(rs.getString("Task").toString());
         }

        }catch (SQLException e1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
        }

     }

     }
```

Comment: If possible please help asap. ---> not applicable on public forums,

Comment: for better help sooner post an MCVE/SSCCE short, runnable, compilable with hardcoded value for JTable/XxxTableModel

Comment: use Swing Action/ActionListener for JButton instead of MouseListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't Want to delete it from database, don't call the dataBase code (on mouse click):

```
  st = con.createStatement();
  ps = con.prepareStatement("delete from "+s+" where id ='" + txtSearch.getText() + "'");
  System.out.println(ps);
  ps.executeUpdate();
  displaydays(s);
```

And add the code to delete the rows something like this :

```
DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(rowName, colName);
table = new JTable(dtm);
dtm.removeRow(0); //remove first row
```

or

```
dtm.removeRow(index);
```

Comment: ok i commented off the dataBase code but  the delete button becomes just an accessory with no form of function at all.. What should i do about that? i want to just delete from jtable.

Comment: @user3868279 Don't delete the button..just comment out the data base code..and add the code which I have given below with your data model you have used

Comment: i have an existing Defaulttablemodel if i were to use yours will it override my existing one? sorry kind of new with table

Comment: Is it tblModel ? Use existing one definitely, just replace the name and try Like :  tblModel.removeRow(0); and see if the 1st row is deleted

Comment: Hi hey thanks able to remove first row. I want to ask one more thing, is there anyway to displayed the edited jtable instead because after i delete the row and refreshed the table the deleted row appears there again (i know its because data was not deleted from database) but is there anyway to displayed edited data even after refreshing.

Comment: yes, there are many logic's you can follow. For eg( Although not recommendable ) just keep a track on primary keys you have removed from table.Now when you load you Model, don't add those primary key values.You got it?

Comment: U mean when i delete then row, i save the primary key of the data and when displaying, i set a false on the primary key and then display the data?Sorry but even if i know the theory, i not sure how to apply it practically.. could u give me an example? Thanks

Comment: You want this for a single run, or anytime it should not show deleted rows

Comment: anytime it should not show the deleted rows. btw i was thinking of creating a button to "view history" so the view history will be able to view all the data from database while the jtable should not show deleted rows. Applicable?

Comment: So its better you create one more column in database.The one you delete, copy it to the another column and delete from the 1st.Like this problem will become very simple and you can show deleted history as well.

Comment: i kind of don't understand what do you mean. Sorry.. hahaha

Comment: Ok If this is my table : student(sid,sname,sno), so add one more column : student(sid,sname,sno,isActive)
Now if you delete from jTable, make isActive 'n' to the particulate record.And when you display data, check if isActive is 'y' ..if its 'n' show it in deleted history.CLEAR?

Comment: Think..any problem ask me

Comment: I tired making the extra column - (Check) with data type Tinyint(1) for making a true or false in the delete but i cant seem to progress with it... Need some hard codes..

Comment: If you think answer was helpful,you can accept it by clicking on green tick